# where is the location of "Recent places" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts

If you type **"Recent"** in Windows 8 run command, explorer goes you to this location:

```
C:\Users\Me\Recent
```

even this location is feeding from another source; and it is:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
```

In windows explorer, under "Favorites", there is location called **"Recent places"** which contains the newly opened folders;

My question is: where is the exact source which this link folder refers to? (like above example)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that the same directory?

Comment: no; "Recent places" just contains folders but "Recent Items" contains both folders and files;

Comment: Are these folders the same as in *Recent items*? Maybe explorer just filters files out.

Comment: it's not the matter of filtering; every lnk needs a reference location;

Comment: That's correct, I mean maybe *Recent places* use the same folder that *Recent*, but show only links that point to directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Recent Places` is a virtual folder, meaning there's no actual directory in the file system for it. As mentioned by @gronostaj, it's a folder-only filtered view of `Recent`.